# Unity3d Triggers not Working With Models?

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor, unity-game-engine

I recently have imported an fbx model into my project, and am trying to use it as a character in my game. I would like to make it pass through my player, so I set the model as a trigger after generating the colliders. However, the model still seems to collide with my player, even though it is a trigger, and all other triggers that I create seem to pass through fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the collider from the model. Your model might have a box collider attached to it.

Comment: Yes, I want the box collider, as I need to call the OnTriggerEnter method, as well as have the model move through characters. Any way to resolve both issues? @ReazMurshed

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/293622/how-can-i-make-two-colliders-pass-through-each-oth.html

Comment: Thanks! Wish there was a more elegant way but whatever works!

Comment: Good to know. Putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might look at this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/293622/how-can-i-make-two-colliders-pass-through-each-oth.html). The trick is using [Physics.IgnoreCollisions](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html).

Attaching the code from the document.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform bulletPrefab;
    void Start() {
        Transform bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab) as Transform;
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(bullet.GetComponent<Collider>(), GetComponent<Collider>());
    }
}
```